# For $p,q$ prime and $p \neq q$ show that $C_p \times C_q \cong C_{pq}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here are my thoughts so far:

- $C_p = \langle x \mid x^p =e\rangle$
- $C_q = \langle y \mid y^q =e\rangle$
- $C_p \times C_q$ has elements of the form $(x^a,y^b)$
- There are $p$ possible values for $x^a$ and $q$ possible values for $y^b$. So there are $pq$ possible elements in $C_p \times C_q$.
- $C_{pq} = \langle z\mid z^{pq} = e\rangle$ and there are $pq$ elements in this group.
- For an isomorphism from $C_p \times C_q$ to $C_{pq}$ we send $(e,e)$ to $e$ to ensure that the identities are mapped to each other. However, I'm not sure how to define an isomorphism for the other elements.

Comment: Hint: can you find an element of order $pq$ in $C_p \times C_q$?

Comment: It would be really easy to go for a map if you can actually look at $C_p$ as $\{\bar{0},\bar{1},\dots,\bar{p-1}\}$ and $C_q$ as $\{\bar{0},\bar{1},\dots,\bar{q-1}\}$... first obvious map would then be... $(\bar{a},\bar{b})\rightarrow ??$

Comment: To add to @universalset's hint: once you find an element of order $pq$, then you can confidently say that $C_p\times C_q$ is cyclic. Cyclic groups of the same order are isomorphic.

Comment: @universalset $(x,y)$ has order $pq$

Answer (score 1):

You know $C_p\simeq \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ so you might as well work with that. Then use $(q,p)=1$ and the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: if you have $g\in G$ of order $n$, $h\in H$ of order $m$, then what's the order of $(g,h)$ in $G\times H$?